# What exactly does U+ stand for and why can't I create a table of Unicode intermediate strings in my C++ application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, utf-8, string-literals

I'm trying to convert an application from Java + Swing to C++ + Qt. At one point I had to deal with some Unicode intermediates. In Java, this was fairly easy:

```
private static String[] hiraganaTable = {
    "\u3042", "\u3044", "\u3046", "\u3048", "\u304a", 
    "\u304b", "\u304d", "\u304f", "\u3051", "\u3053", 
    ...
}
```

...whereas in C++ I'm having problems:

```
QString hiraganaTable[] = {
    "\x30\x42", "\x30\x44", "\x30\x46", "\x30\x48", "\x30\x4a", 
    "\x30\x4b", "\x30\x4d", "\x30\x4f", "\x30\x51", "\x30\x53", 
    ...
};
```

I couldn't use \u in VS2008 because I got a heap of warnings of the form:

> character represented by universal-character-name '\u3042' cannot be represented in the current code page (1250)

And don't call me stupid, I tried to use File->Advanced Save Options to no avail, the codepage didn't seem to change at all. Seems like this is a known problem: [How to create a UTF-8 string literal in Visual C++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688760/how-to-create-a-utf-8-string-literal-in-visual-c-2008)

The table I'm using is fairly short, so with the help of Vim and some introductory-level regexp-magic, I was able to convert it to **\x30\x42** notation. Unfortunately, the QStrings would not initialize properly from such an input. I tried everything. fromAscii(), fromUtf8(), fromLocal8Bit(), QString(QByteArray), the works. Then, trying to write U+3042 without BOM to a file and then viewing it in hex mode, I found out it actually turns out to be **"E3 81 82"**. Suddenly, an entry like this seemed to work with **QString::fromAscii()**. Now I'm left wondering how much does exactly the "U+" stand for in "U+3042" (since 0xE38182 - 0x3042 = E35140, maybe I'd better add this Magic Constant to all my would-be Unicode chars?). How should I proceed from here to get an array of proper UTF-8 strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that C++ is based on C, which dates back to the ASCII age. The "default" C strings "abc" are 8 bits. Your Visual C++ compiler has 16 bits Unicode (UTF-16) literals, though, with a slightly different syntax: `L"abc\u3042"`. The type of such literals is `wchar_t[N]` instead of `char[N]`, you can store them in a `std::wstring`.

Qt fully understands `wchar_t` and QStrings can be directly constructed from them without conversion problems.

Comment: What about portability of L"? I'd like to build the code with g++ some day and I suppose this might cause problems.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem until you go outside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane). I.e. Byzantine music notes might be a problem, or ancient Sumerian.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the UTF-8 encoding of that character.

```
>>> u'\u3042'.encode('utf-8').encode('hex')
'e38182'
```

If you write them all out in UTF-8 then you should be fine.

The "U+" just indicates that you're looking at a Unicode codepoint as opposed to some specific encoding.

**EDIT:**

A small scriptlet to help you get started, in Python (same language as above):

```
>>> print ',\n'.join(', '.join('"%s"' % (y.encode('utf-8').encode('string-escape')
      ,) for y in x) for x in [u'あいうえお', u'かきくけこ', u'さしすせそ'])
"\xe3\x81\x82", "\xe3\x81\x84", "\xe3\x81\x86", "\xe3\x81\x88", "\xe3\x81\x8a",
"\xe3\x81\x8b", "\xe3\x81\x8d", "\xe3\x81\x8f", "\xe3\x81\x91", "\xe3\x81\x93",
"\xe3\x81\x95", "\xe3\x81\x97", "\xe3\x81\x99", "\xe3\x81\x9b", "\xe3\x81\x9d"
```

Answer (score 2):

"U+*dddd*" where each *d* is a hexadecimal digit denotes a Unicode code point.

You cannot store 16-bit values in 8-bit chars; that's the main problem you're having.

Use wide characters, e.g. (these are string literals) `L"\0x3042"` or `L"\u3042"`.

Then figure out how to make QString accept those.

Note: Visual C++ will emit sillywarning for the `\U` notation used within literals, while g++ will emit sillywarnings for that notation used outside literals.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Actually, Unicode code points are U+PPDDDD, where PP is a hex value between 00 and 10 (so, 17 values) and DDDD is any four hex digits.  Unicode is a 21-bit character set, **not** a 16-bit character set.

Comment: @tchrist right, but that's unnecessary detail. there's a heck of a lot to be said about unicode. i could go on for several thousand pages. also about SO, by the way. i note that impractical but clever-looking answers that don't really answer the question, get upvoted (in general). argh. cheers,

Comment: I just get nervous about people claiming that Unicode characters are 16-bit values.  That's the kind of thinking that locks people into UCS-2 and the BMP. Know what I mean? Then they could never have the wonderful U+01F47D, EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN, in their code. :)

Comment: @tchrist: nothing wrong with UCS-2. in fact for portable code the OP had better limit himself to 16-bit values and encode UTF-16 pairs explicitly if such a Unicode character is needed. because `wchar_t` is 16 bits in Windows (it would be the same kind of problem as the original). Cheers & hth.,