# Do < and > on C++ strings reflect alphabetical ordering?

Tags: c++, string

I have a question about alphabetical order of strings in C++. Let us say i  have two strings:

```
    string x="asd123";
    string y="asd136";
```

Can we compare these strings with < or > operators? For example: can we say

```
    if(x>y)
    cout<<".....";
```

Does that always work? Thanks.

Comment: read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The strings are compared lexicographically (dictionary style), with a string that's a shorter subset of another string coming before the longer one. But *it's not necessarily alphabetical*; it's according to the underlying character encoding. Most systems these days use ASCII, so lowercase letters come out in order, and uppercase characters come out in order, and uppercase characters come before lowercase characters.

Comment: A-Z letters. Non-English "special" characters, such as å, ä, ö, ń, ǹ, í, ì, é, è, ë, and lots of other similar things do not sort at all well without further work.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, comparing `std::string`s with [`std::string::operator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) always works. The strings are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). This means that each corresponding element of the two strings is compared in turn until two are found that are not equal, and that ordering determines the order of the strings.

The lexicographic ordering performs `<` on each element of the `std::basic_string`. That is, for a `std::string`, each `char` will be compared using `<`. It will simply compare the values of those `char`s. As far as C++ is concerned, a `char` is just a numeric value. These values are mapped to the characters in a string literal by the *execution character set* (which, for a modern C++ compiler, is almost always at least ASCII compatible).

Comment: @pst: `string` is a collection of bytes, not of characters. Comparison is by byte value. No free lunch.

Comment: @sftrabbit: MSVC, one of the biggest compilers, [does not default to UTF8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688760/how-to-create-a-utf-8-string-literal-in-visual-c-2008)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks - I'm not very familiar with MSVC.

Comment: @MooingDuck - an implementation can't use UTF8 for `std::string`, because `char_traits<char>` is **required** to implement `eq` and `lt` to give the same results as `==` and `<`.