# Euro Symbol for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, char

I am creating a small currency converting program in C++ in Visual Studio 2013.

For a pound sign, I have created a char variable using the Windows-1252 code for £ symbol.

```
const char poundSign(156);
```

I need to find a way in which I can implement a symbol for €, euro symbol. When I run the program.

Comment: That is not ASCII. Did you mean [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)?

Comment: code-pages are the worst thing that happened (for non-americans of course). Use Unicode. Preferably utf8. I know c++ standard support for utf8 is abysmal, but there are options like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) and [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Related: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19987448/509868) question, which uses UTF-8 (may be better than UCS-16)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any of the deprecated [extended ASCII encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) as they are long obsolete nowadays.  As user1937198 said, `156` is the character code of `£` in the archaic [Windows-1252* encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  The appearance of non-ASCII characters in these encodings depends on the [codepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752(v=vs.85).aspx) selected by the user, which makes it impossible to mix characters from different codepages under such a scheme. Additionally, your users will be very confused if they pick the wrong codepage.

Consider using [Unicode](http://unicode.org) instead.  Since you're on Windows, [you should probably use UTF-16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081(v=vs.85).aspx), in which case the correct way is to declare:

```
// make sure the source code is saved as UTF-16!
const wchar_t poundSign[] = L"£";
const wchar_t euroSign[]  = L"€";
```

In UTF-16, there's no guarantee that a single character will take only 1 character due to the [surrogate mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069(v=vs.85).aspx), hence it's best to store "characters"* as strings.

Keep in mind that this means the rest of your program should switch to Unicode as well: use the "W" versions of the Windows API (the `WCHAR`-versions).

[*] In technical lingo, each "Unicode character" is referred to as a code point.

Comment: @DieterLücking: sure, but that's what Microsoft chose to stick with :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the translation environment and the execution environment.
E.g., it heavily depends on where your program is being run what *glyph* is assigned to the *character* you intended to produce (cf. 'codepage').

You may want to check of your terminal or whatsoever is unicode-aware and then just use the appropriate codepoints.

Also, you should not create character constants the way you did. Use a character literal instead.