# unicode char in linux doesn't work in windows

Tags: linux, windows, unicode, character-encoding

I have a program in Linux (Ubuntu 13.04) in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* cp = "ӐҖ";
    printf("%s\n",cp);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*cp));
    printf("%d\n",(unsigned int)*cp);
    return 0;
}
```

The first and second printf has ouput of:

```
ӐҖ
1
```

respectively.

1.) My first concern is that, in the 3rd printf, I tried to cast the character to unsigned int in an attempt to see that unicode codepoint that represents that first character but I am getting -45. What should be the best approach I should use to see the unicode codepoint of a single unicode character that is represented by a 1 byte "char" data type?

2.) Second concern, when I port this code to Windows 7, [char* cp = "ӐҖ";] will result to a compiler "warning C4566 : character represented by universal-character name '\uFFE6' cannot be represented in the current code page (932)". When I run it,the output are:

```
??
1
```

Does Windows don't support unicode in "char" data type? Then what character data type should I use to make my code portable from Linux to Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't support Unicode. Neither does C++. There are libraries for that if you're interested, or you can hand-roll your own routines if you need.

`char` in C is not a "character" type, it's a **byte** type. I'm assuming you wrote your source code in UTF-8.

GCC interprets bytes in string literals literally. You have defined a sequence of 5 bytes: `d3 90 d2 96 00`. (`d3` interpreted as signed char is -45.) You can try to use `strlen`, it should return 4. Most Unix and C API's are byte-oriented, so when you print out those bytes, what shows up on the screen depends on the encoding used by your terminal emulator. Usually it's UTF-8, so everything works.

If the source is in UTF-8, MSVC treats string and char literals as what you want to be displayed – that is, as text – and then encodes them in your system's default codepage. So if you write `"à"`, it will be reencoded to `e0 00` if you use CP-1252. If you use encoding that has no `à` (for example you use CP-1250, which has `ŕ` at `e0`), you will get a question mark.

But how MSVC knows what text was in the file? It looks for UTF-8 BOM. If your text file doesn't start with a BOM, MSVC assumes the encoding of the file is the default system encoding and doesn't try converting anything – it leaves the bytes as it saw them, just like GCC.

(Note: I see you use ShiftJIS; it may cause problems as it's not ASCII-compatible and I don't know how MSVC handles it. Proceed with caution.)

If you need to handle Unicode text and use MSVC, you can also use [wide string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kc54dd5.aspx). GCC supports them as well, although it lacks many library functions that can use them. But I'm a strong supporter of [UTF-8 manifesto](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) and I recommend using UTF-8 strings as often as possible.

Note that if you remove BOM, you no longer can use wide string literals in MSVC.

EDIT: see here for more discussion and experiences of Asian developers with MSCV: [How to create a UTF-8 string literal in Visual C++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688760/how-to-create-a-utf-8-string-literal-in-visual-c-2008) Long story short: it's not pretty.

Comment: C++11 adds more support for Unicode to the core C++ language beyond just *wide literals* (via the `L` literal prefix). It introduces new data types for 16/32-bit characters, new prefixes for UTF-8/16/32 literals, new `basic_string` typedefs for UTF-16/32 strings, and new `std::codecvt` types for UTF data conversions.