# Compare iterated character from std::string with unicode C++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

i've been struggling with this problem for quite some time and this is my first for dealing with unicode or UTF-8 basically.

This is what i'm trying to do, I just want to iterate a std::string containing with combination from normal alphabet and a unicode symbol, which in my case is en dash "–". more info: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

this is the code that i've tried and it won't run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "test string with symbol – and !";
    for (auto &letter : str) {
        if (letter == "–") {
            std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result of my compiler:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and 
integer [-fpermissive]
     if (letter == "–") {
                   ^
```

also, when i was looking through the internet i found an interesting information for this type of task that i need to solve. [How to search a non-ASCII character in a c++ string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396151/how-to-search-a-non-ascii-character-in-a-c-string)

But when i tried to modified my code with those UTF-8 hex code, it also won't run:

```
    if (letter == "\xE2\x80\x93") {
        std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
    }
```

with the exact same message from my compiler, which is c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.

Did i miss something? or do i need to use libraries like ICU or Boost? 
Your help is much appreciated. thank you!

**Update**

based on the answer from UnholySheep, i've been improving my code but it's still cannot work. it can pass the compiling but when i tried to run it, it can't ouput "found!" to out. so, how do i solve this? thank you.

Comment: `"-"` is a *string* literal (which has a type of `const char[]`, but decays to a pointer in the comparison), you cannot compare a `char` to a string literal this way

Comment: oh i see. okay i will check it out

Comment: `if (letter == "\xE2\x80\x93")` doesn't work for several reasons, one being that you try to compare one character to three characters. If you look closely at the linked answer, it uses the `find` member of `std::string`. That function can find substrings with more than one `char` in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring str = L"test string with symbol – and !";
    for (auto &letter : str) {
        if (letter == L'–') {
            std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow this is run. I thought you only use wstring with windows system only (i'm using linux). thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As said in comment by UnholySheep, a char literal `"–"` is a char array. Assuming an utf8 representation, `char em_dash = "–";` is the same as `char em_dash = {'\xe2', '\x80', '\x93'};`.

You can only find true characters with your current code. For example this would work correctly:

```
...
if (letter == '!')
...
```

because `'!'` is a char constant.

If you only want to process unicode characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (code below 0xFFFF), using wide characters should be enough as proposed in @ArashMohammadi's answer. An alternate solution for characters outside the BMP like [emoji chars](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) would be to use a `std::u32string` in which every unicode char is represented by a single `char32_t` character.

If you want to directly process a UTF8 encoded string of single byte characters, you will have to use the `compare` method:

```
std::string em_dash = "–"; // or "\xe2\x80\x93"
...
    for (size_t pos=0; pos <= str.size() - em_dash.size(); pos++) {
        if (str.compare(pos, em_dash.size(), em_dash()) == 0) {
            std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
...
```

or directly use the `find` method:

```
...
    if (str.find(em_dash) != str.npos) {
        std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
    }
...
```