# Problems with french words in using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program in french. When I want to display french characters in QMessageBox, it was replaced by a "?" with a black background.I've tried that:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

QMessageBox::information( this,  QString::fromUtf8("Fenêtre"), tr("Est-ce 
que vous voulez terminer cette simulation?"),tr("Oui"), tr("Non"), 0, 1 )
```

Any ideas about how I could solve this problem?
Thanks for your replies. I'm using Qt 5.1 on VS2010.

Comment: You have to save the file in correct encoding.

Comment: I suggest to use translation module of Qt: `QObject::tr` without non-ascii characters, and in ts files, you use correct translations (with non-ascii characters).

Comment: This might be a font issue. All fonts are not made equal with respect to non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, but it still doesn't work. It displays the same symbole. And I have verified that Qt Creator's default encoding is UTF-8, even I just use Qt Designer for my interface.

Comment: @mouviciel So, It can't solve the problem because of the fonts?

Comment: You should use only <127 ascii characters in your code. If you need non-english text - you should provide tr/ts files. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html

Comment: I would suggest to split, and have `auto title = QString::fromUtf8("Fenêtre");` and check in debugger `title` content (You can also test `"Fen\xC3\xAAtre"`, `ê` is not utf-8) (so you can know from where there is an error). (but in reality, I would simply do `auto title = tr("Window");`)

Comment: @P.Don: It seems you already use some, you have `tr("Oui")`.

Comment: @P.Don: Please check for your code file which encoding is in the first combo from VS menu FILE->Advanced Save Options...

Comment: @olya Thanks, you remind me of that, but I tried and it doesn't change...

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for your help. First, I used directly  `tr("windows")`     but It still display the  `windows` without translation, I don't know why. Second, when I debugger  `title` by using `auto title = QString::fromUtf8("Fenêtre")`; it display  `"Fen?tre"` . Third,test of    `"Fen\xC3\xAAtre" ` can work right. But I'm confused how does it work...By the way, `utf-8` can not represent all of those characters? I'm a new...And Thanks again!

Comment: You may try `QString::fromLatin1("Fenêtre")` (or `QString::fromUtf8(u8"Fenêtre")`).

Comment: @Jarod42 THE ANSWER IS LATIN1!!!`QString::fromLatin1("Fenêtre")`

Comment: @P.Don. `QString.fromUtf8()` requires **bytes** that are encoded as "utf-8". The text "Fenêtre" encoded as "utf-8" is `"Fen\xc3\xaatre"`. In C++ source code, a plain string-literal will be interpreted using the *local encoding* (even if the file is encoded as "utf-8"). If the local encoding is not "utf-8", any undecodable characters will be replaced by `?` in the return value of `QString.fromUtf8()`. So you should use `QString.fromLatin1()` instead.

Comment: Then you could directly put your `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale` as Latin1 and don't bother with `QString::fromLatin1`everywhere. Though if your file is really encoded in UTF-8 it does not make sense...

Comment: @ekhumoro By the way `setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8")` can not change the **local encoding**?

Comment: @P.Don. If `tr("windows")` doesn't work, it has nothing to do with encodings. There must be a problem with how you are using the translation files. I suggest you ask a new question about this, and give more details. As for `setCodecForLocale`: I think this will work if you use it with `QString::fromLocal8Bit()`.

Comment: @P.Don. PS: you might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/688760/984421), and experiment with some of the suggested solutions (not just those in the accepted answer). There are obviously complications with Windows and Visual Studio that go beyond the comments I made above. I can't test any of this myself, since I don't have access to a machine with that setup.

Comment: @ekhumoro OK! You are so nice, I'll take a look of that question later, because I have something else to do rightnow. Thanks again!